# Mistake when trying to make a MediaPlayer in external class

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm using an external class for creation and controlling Android MediaPlayer:

```
    public CycleVideo(String path, Activity activity, FrameLayout  container){
    this.path = path;
    this.activity =activity;
    this.container = container;
}

public void prepare(){

    AssetFileDescriptor  str;

    try {

        str = activity.getAssets().openFd(path);
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setDataSource(str.getFileDescriptor());
        SurfaceView sw = new SurfaceView(activity.getApplicationContext());
        sw.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        container.addView(sw);
        sw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mp.setDisplay(sw.getHolder());
        mp.prepare();
        //for testing - start
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.start();
        //for testing - stop

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

In the main activity, i'm using this:

```
        FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.PictureContainerLayout);
    CycleVideo v = new CycleVideo("[path to video file in assets]", this, container);
    v.prepare();
```

But the frame layout in my activity is still empty, when i'm launching my application. And there is no any errors in LogCat of Eclipse. Where did i made a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Your SurfaceView is empty.
see : 
http://blog.wisecells.com/2012/06/04/surface-view-android/
for use SurfaceView and holder.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the call to `getApplicationContext()`. An `Activity` overrides `Context`, so you don't need it.

```
SurfaceView sw = new SurfaceView(activity);
```